# Style a javascript form to have users "sign on the line?"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a simple interface that replicates the idea of "signing" a document by providing a line on which users can place their name to begin registration. I'm trying to find some way have providing users with a nice line to write on, rather than the standard box. Does anyone know any tricks to achieve this?

Comment: `nice line to write on` is rather subjective.  Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Kenneth basically nailed it in his answer... Remove the standard "box" appearance leaving only a border on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could style an input box like this:

```
<input type="text" class="linebox" />

.linebox{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```